# strtok getting segmentation error read file

Tags: c++, c, linux

Getting segmentation fault on strtok, i have my input string `lyne` defined as char array instead of pointer but does not seem to work. this is in C and linux

```
    typedef struct 
    {
    int x;
    char *y;
    } child;

    typedef struct{
    child *details;
    }  parent;


        fp = fopen(filename,"r"); // read mode
        char lyne[25];
        char *item;
    fgets(lyne,25,fp);  

    parent record;
        record.details= malloc (5  * sizeof(child));    

        while (fgets(lyne,25,fp)) {

            printf("test %s \n",lyne);

            item = strtok(lyne," ");    

strcpy(record.details->y,item);//seg error on this line
        }
        fclose(fp);


my file looks like this
file#1
ABC 100
BCE 200


OUTPUT:
test ABC 100

Segmentation fault
```

Comment: @jxh: What do you think the `printf` call is doing, if not producing output?

Comment: [Works for me](http://ideone.com/COSpAv). The problem must needs lie elsewhere, in the code you haven't shown.

Comment: @jxh: Which is exactly what the OP shows. The line "file#1" is skipped; the output starts with the second line.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: It was not at all clear to me that "file#1" is part of the input. Since you say so, I'll give the asker the benefit of the doubt on that point.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik i update my code, now i think its related to my struct value assgiment.

Comment: The first parameter to `strcpy` should point to a valid buffer of sufficient size. `record.details->y` instead is uninitialized, contains garbage, points to some random address in memory.

Comment: yep got it (char *) malloc(24); and now its working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not allocated the memory to the struct child member 'y' as your structure is

```
typedef struct 
    {
    int x;
    char *y;
    } child;
```

What you have to do is :

```
record.details->y = malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(item) + 1));
strcpy(record.details->y,item);
```

Answer (score 0):

Had to add
`parent.deatils->y = (char *) malloc(24);` before using it